# Can not get NUnit Runner task working

Tags: continuous-integration, nunit, bamboo, nunit-3.0, nunit-console

I've created NUnit Runner task, but it failes all the time.
As an executable I'm using nunit3-console.exe

My tests in .net 4.6.1 test project use NUnit3
This is how the job is configured:
[nunit job configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svVhs.png)

After plan run I've got error:

```
Could not find test result reports in the C:\Users\dw\bamboo-home\xml- data\build-dir\DWT-BW-JOB1 directory.
Invalid argument: -xml=BW\14\TestResult.xml
```

I've found that is because NUnit runner task on Bamboo is designed to work with NUnit2. The "-xml" argument is not supported in NUnit3 console runner.

I've found somebody found a solution, but it does not work for me: http://vijayshinva.github.io/devops/bamboo/nunit/tdd/ci/2016/02/25/configure-atlassian-bamboo-nunit-runner-to-execute-nunit-3-tests.html

In my case I've got another error:

```
Could not find test result reports in the C:\Users\dw\bamboo-home\xml- data\build-dir\DWT-BW-JOB1 directory.
'nunit3-console.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Please, help resolve this issue. Thank you

Comment: Is nunit3-console.exe on your path?

Comment: in my path is D:\durova\NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.4.1\tools\runNunit3.bat file with code:

    `@echo off 
    SET "var=%*"
    CALL SET var=%%var:--result=TestResults.xml
    nunit3-console.exe %var%;format=nunit3`

Comment: I suggest you turn on echo and see what is being executed. Post the result in your question rather than a comment, so it can be formatted in a way that is readable.